# when using plugin cvim, \if meas insert a function with comments. but the format is wrong

Tags: vim

well, as the title says. the following is what looks like now in my c++ source code:

```
  1 
  2 /*                                  
  3 * ===  FUNCTION  =============================================================
  4 *         Name:  sample_function    
  5 *  Description:
  6     * =============================================================================
  7     */
  8     void sample_function ( <+argument_list+> )                                                                                                                       
  9     {
 10         return <+return_value+>;
 11     }       /* -----  end of function sample_function  ----- */
```

when i looked up the 
c-support/templates/cpp.idioms.template 
or 
c-support/templates/c.idioms.template
everything is right.

it seems like when insert the template code ,vim format it again by itself.

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic indenting interferes with the way that the template is inserted. You should report this issue to the plugin's author.

You can temporarily work around the problem by turning off indenting; depending on your indent settings one of:

```
:set nocindent noautoindent nosmartindent indentexpr=
```

Comment: well,the above solution only takes effect in vim session. While save it in vimrc will not works.

Comment: Yes, because the indent method is probably set by `ftplugin/c.vim`. And you probably still want auto-indenting, don't you?! As I said, this has to be fixed in the plugin itself.